# How to resolve the "pointer like" in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the code below:

```
class A { }

class B
{
    public List<A> LstClassA;
    public static A CurrentA;

    public void AddA(A a)
    {
        LstClassA.Add(a);
        CurrentA = a;
    }
}
```

And when I want do somethings in `CurrentA` (like change some properties), it not take effect to instance in `LstClassA`, how can I make the changing of `CurrentA` take effect to other `A` instance?

**Update**
The class B is:

```
class B
{
    public List<A> LstClassA;
    public static A CurrentA;

    public void AddA(A a)
    {
        LstClassA.Add(a);
    }
}
```

I just want to store current item which is processing in static member for easy manipulation :D

**Update 2**

For example, i have `class Project` like this:

```
class Project
{
}
```

and `class Solution` (which contains more projects)

```
class Solution
{
public List<Project> LstProject;
public static Project CurrentProject;
}
```

and some where in the code:

```
Project prj = new Project()
sol.LstProject.Add(prj);
```

and

```
Solution.CurrentProject = prj;
```

the problem is what i have done in `CurrentProject` doesn't make the changed to instance in the list

Comment: it should change the value to the last item that is added. If it does not, it means there is some special handling in the class (May be properties you are trying to change are struct, or class is immutable or something similar)

Comment: Since `A` is a class (which is a reference type), as long as you're modifying the same instance, it should affect anything else that has a reference to it.  There must be something more you're not showing us.

Comment: I can't understand what you want. Try posting an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of the class `B`? As `CurrentA` is static, all instances of `B` will share the same variable. `CurrentA` will only contain the last `A` instance added to any of the `B` instances.

Comment: I don't see any pointer code.

Comment: @Ramhound It's there, it's just hidden.  All reference types can be though of as pointers, they are simply hidden from you and you have somewhat more limited operations on what you can do with them than in say C or C++ (for example you can do pointer arithmetic and add an integer to a pointer).

Comment: @Guffa: yeap, that is what i mean but my english too bad :-(

Comment: Ok what's the deal with all the posted answers from people who have no idea how C# works?

Comment: @MikeChristensen All of the people who know how C# works know that there is nothing wrong with the code that's posted; the problem must be in some code that's not there, so none of the knowledgeable people are answering.  The only people willing to answer are those that think there's something wrong with the posted code (when there's not).

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to have a static reference to the "current" item like this.  It's not clear how you're using it, but it really smells like a bad idea from what I can see.  There's probably a better way of approaching the problem to begin with.

Comment: So, what is the problem, really? When you make updates to `CurrentA` some instance of `A` is updated, but is it that the wrong instance gets updated? Which instance do you expect to be updated?

Comment: I have just updated the question to make some sense ;)

Comment: @BìnhNguyên In all of your examples, including the most recent one, modifying the variable in either location (the field or within the list) will be reflected in both places.  Giving different names to the classes isn't changing anything.  Please provide a compilable example that we can run, along with actual and desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think following will be approximately what you want (not static, but you do have instance already to call Add, don't you):

```
public A CurrentA {
  get { return LstClassA.LastOrDefault(); }
}
```

I totally agree with your smiley that making static field for "easy manipulation" makes not much sense (unless I read your smiley wrong). Static fields that change "randomly" are good source of long debugging sessions.

Comment: How do you know that the last item in the list will be the most recently changed item?

Comment: @Servy, I don't :) from all identical samples it looked like OP is treating last item as current... But OP probably needs something totally different (like simply pass "current" as argument to all `HandleCurrentItem` functions).